# NSTimer and UICollectionView

Tags: nstimer, uicollectionview

I can show some code if necessary, but I don't believe my question will need it because it's fairly general.

I have a UIView that has a UICollectionView in it.  It's a 10 x 10 grid with a custom layout.  I have it custom simply because I want it to scroll both side to side and up and down.

I also have a NSTimer running a countdown clock.  The NSTimer runs smoothly except when the user scrolls the UICollectionView.  In fact, when a user scrolls it in any direction the NSTimer stops completely, then, when the user stops, the timer begins again right where it left off.

I've used an NSTimer many times and never saw a simple user interaction causing it to stop.

Is there any way to avoid this from happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this.. Add your timer to main run loop

```
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a note on this.  You do have to wait until you start the NSTimer before you can put this code.  It will crash with a nil NSTimer object.

Thanks again.

Comment: Ofcourse.. You should create the timer before adding it to the runloop. Can you accept my answer if tit helps